# Matlab GUIDE callback does not update handles even when guidata is used

Tags: matlab, timer, callback, matlab-guide

I am working from the timer GUIDE callback example provided by Mathworks as a minimal working example. The files can be obtained with:

```
copyfile(fullfile(docroot, 'techdoc','creating_guis','examples',...
'ex_guide_timergui*.*')), fileattrib('ex_guide_timergui*.*', '+w')
```

in Matlab.
I modified the example file like so:

```
function startbtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to startbtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% START USER CODE
% Only start timer if it is not running
if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'off')
    start(handles.timer);
end
handles.blip = 1;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Essentially creating the blip field in handles when I click the start pushbutton (and start the timer) in the example. I then update the master version of handles by using giudata...or so I thought.

I modified the timer callback function to test for this field:

```
function update_display(hObject,eventdata,hfigure)
% Timer timer1 callback, called each time timer iterates.
% Gets surface Z data, adds noise, and writes it back to surface object.

handles = guidata(hfigure);
Z = get(handles.surf,'ZData');
Z = Z + 0.1*randn(size(Z));
set(handles.surf,'ZData',Z);
if handles.blip ==1
    a = 0;
end
```

However as soon as I run the GUI and start the timer, MATLAB throws an error saying that blip doesn't exist as a field in handles (reference to non-existent field 'blip'). How can this be when I use guidata to update the master version of handles in the previously called callback, and then retrieve this master version using guidata in the timer callback (code originally in the example)? I should have the updated version with the blip field but I do not. Debugging step by step shows that the handles version retrieved by the timer callback corresponds to the version made by the openingfunction, with the blip field missing.
I have looked for solutions to this problem on this site and using google, but haven't found an explanation (or a way to do this using only callbacks not functions) - some have succeeded with functions but here the timer functionality is what prevents me from writing a regular function to do the same thing and calling it from a callback.

Comment: Timers execute their `TimerFcn` immediately on start, so `update_display` is being executed before `handles.blip = 1;` is set. Your modifications to `handles` need to be before the timer is started.

Comment: That is correct! I had not expected this and updating guidata before starting the timer has fixed the problem. Many thanks :). I would upvote but I believe I need more reputation... I'll create an answer and accept it so others can benefit if they were having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by excaza in the comments: the reason why this is happening is because the timer functions are immediately called upon the timer being started in MATLAB regardless of what the timer period is, thereby checking the value before it's been set. A workaround is to make changes to variables before starting the timer, update guidata then start the timer (and eventually update guidata again).